# how to pass parameters to methods which are executed by groups in testng.xml?

Tags: testng

I have two test methods

```java
@Test (groups = {"group1"})
public test1(){
}
@Test (groups = {"group1"})
public test2(){
}
```

Now I want to execute these test cases using groups in testng.xml

for example

```xml
<suite>
  <test>
    <groups> 
        <run>
           <include name="group1"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Now here I want to pass parameters to test1 and test2 individually like

```xml
<include name="test1"><parameter name="abc"  value="ABC"/></include>
<include name="test2"><parameter name="def"  value="DEF"/></include>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can  use dataprovider.

Comment: could you please give me example with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass parameter from testng xml file. you have define the parameter in test and pass it from xml as given below.

```
@Test (groups = {"group1"})
@Paramters({"parameter1"})
public test1(String arg1){
   System.out.println(arg1);
}

@Test (groups = {"group1"})
@Paramters({"parameter2"})
public test2(String arg2){
   System.out.println(arg2);

}
```

You can pass it from xml as given below.

```
<suite>
  <test>
    <parameter name="parameter1" value="test1"/>
    <parameter name="parameter2" value="Test2"/>
    <groups> 
        <run>
           <include name="group1"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
  </test>
</suite>
```

You can pass values using data provider but it is taken the values from the source, no need to mention it from the testNG xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataprovider with Method class to pass diff parameter to your test method. refer this  [link](https://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html)

```
 @Test (groups = {"group1"},dataProvider="test")
    public test1(){
    }
    @Test (groups = {"group1"},dataProvider="test")
    public test2(){
    } 

    @DataProvider(name="test")
        public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(Method m){
            if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test1")){
            return new Object[][] {
                    {  "ABC" },

                };}
            else{
            return new Object[][] {
                    { "DEF" },

                };}       
        }
    }
```